# WebService on IIS7 returning "The data is invalid", but works in ASP.NET Development server

Tags: iis-7, soap, web-services

I'm losing my nerves with an error that I never have encountered before: I set up a simple SOAP web service, that runs on .net 4, which receives a string as the input and returns a XMLDocument.

When testing the service in the developer environment, i.e. the ASP.NET development server, everything works fine, however when I put the WS on the IIS7 server, the server refuses to process the request and returns a Error 500, stating: "**Server was unable to process request - The data is invalid.**"

I test the WS from a client that is located in the same network, but different machine. The SOAP request that is sent from the client is modeled exactly the same as demanded by the WS. The request is without doubt correct, as I manage to properly call the WS from a local client, communicating with "localhost".

Are there perhaps some extra settings I need to configure on the IIS7?

Cheers,
Alois

Answer (score 0):

I would check for the path that is used to read the XML doc to make sure that it's calculated correctly in IIS too.  If you're using something like Server.MapPath and your site has a different vdir structure, that could do it.

Also test by returning a simple hello world rather than the full xml doc to see if that makes a difference and helps you narrow down the cause.

If you're using WCF, it's particular about the binding.  Your IIS binding name needs to be the same as WCF expects.  That's a question for stackoverflow.com, but it's something to look at.

Also check the IIS logs to see if there is a substatus code to gives more clues.